# How to get bytes from ZipEntry without using ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, zipinputstream

Is there a way to make this a little simpler? Since I need the bytes of each entry is there any way to get them without using the ByteArrayOutputStream

```
public UnzippedFile unzip(ZipFile zipFile) throws IOException {
    var unzippedFile = new UnzippedFile();
    try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = ZipUtils.toZipInputStream(zipFile)) {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try (var file = new ByteArrayOutputStream(buffer.length)) {
                while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    file.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                unzippedFile.addFileToMap(entry.getName(), file.toByteArray());
            }
        }
    }
    return unzippedFile;
}
```

My UnzippedFile class:

```
public class UnzippedFile {
    @Getter
    private final Map<String, byte[]> filesMap;

    public UnzippedFile() {
        this.filesMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addFileToMap(String name, byte[] file) {
        filesMap.put(name, file);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could simplify the body of your `while` loop with [`InputStream#readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()), assuming you're using Java 9+.

Comment: @Slaw I am using 17, could you show in a comment/answer exactly where please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java 9+ then you should be able to simplify that code with [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()).

```java
public UnzippedFile unzip(ZipFile zipFile) throws IOException {
    var unzippedFile = new UnzippedFile();
    try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = ZipUtils.toZipInputStream(zipFile)) {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String name = entry.getName();
            byte[] file = zipInputStream.readAllBytes();

            unzippedFile.addFileToMap(name, file);
        }
    }
    return unzippedFile;
}
```

Comment: Will try it out and leave feedback, thank you, it will give me the bytes of each entry in the zip right? or is it the bytes of all zip?

Comment: `readAllBytes()` essentially does exactly what you already have for you. It reads all the bytes until there are no more to read. And `ZipInputStream` does this per `ZipEntry`. So, it will only read the bytes of the current entry.